# Need help with btrfs partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount, swap, btrfs

I installed ubuntu with custom partition layout.

```
boot/efi

root (/) as btrfs

home (/home) as btrfs

swap partition
```

lsblk looks like :

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS

nvme0n1 259:0 0 953,9G 0 disk├─

nvme0n1p1 259:1 0 1,2G 0 part /boot/efi├─

nvme0n1p2 259:2 0 230,5G 0 part /swap│ /├─

nvme0n1p3 259:3 0 705,8G 0 part /home└─

nvme0n1p4 259:4 0 16,3G 0 part
```

blkid looks like :

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="c7fad709-d03d-4dad-9061-777e3ce28cb8" UUID_SUB="02ff67a2-776c-43e0-88ea-758fbe5e9e66" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="e215ee62-71f1-d842-9899-d3b0c69b8f9d"

/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="4922-93B0" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="18339df2-89fb-4812-9a4d-733a9b247b86" /dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="732d2f91-1a80-44cd-a651-384988bccd66" TYPE="swap"

PARTUUID="4696a283-cdc7-4452-bc16-53969c04de89" /dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="7e1daa09-4f81-4a7e-88f4-8708f6d242e5" UUID_SUB="7f3eebfd-aa46-4dda-b9ad-b394312f6d8f" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"

PARTUUID="07ca766f-2c54-4c3e-893b-e9795b215637"
```

Also FSTAB looks like :

```
UUID=4922-93B0                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults   0 2
UUID=7e1daa09-4f81-4a7e-88f4-8708f6d242e5 /              btrfs   subvol=/@,defaults,noatime,autodefrag 0 0
UUID=7e1daa09-4f81-4a7e-88f4-8708f6d242e5 /swap          btrfs   subvol=/@swap,subvol=/@swap,defaults 0 0
UUID=c7fad709-d03d-4dad-9061-777e3ce28cb8 /home          btrfs   defaults,noatime,autodefrag 0 0
/swap/swapfile                            swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
```

At first it doesnt look ok for me. Am I wrong ? Also swap partition is not visible or active

can someone take a look and help me ?

thanks